# Getting Error response: 404 The specified blob does not exist while using EventProcessorClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-sdk

I just updated our EventHub event reading from `EventHubConsumerClient.ReadEventsAsync` to `EventProcessorClient` as per the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.consumer.eventhubconsumerclient.readeventsasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-eventhubs-consumer-eventhubconsumerclient-readeventsasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) under the `ReadEventsAsync` method.

The `EventProcessorClient` makes use of checkpointing which requires an Azure storage Container to store blobs. Although all of the messages (as far as I've checked) coming into the EventHub are being handled the client throws the `Error response [response-id] 404 The specified blob does not exist.` warning every time it is started.

The warning is thrown in the snippet below right before the `_logger.LogInformation` is called:

```
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            EventProcessorClient processorClient = _processorClient.Value
                ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(_processorClient.Value));

            processorClient.ProcessEventAsync += _deviceToCloudMessageHandler.EventHandler;
            processorClient.ProcessErrorAsync += _deviceToCloudMessageHandler.ErrorHandler;

            await processorClient.StartProcessingAsync(cancellationToken);

            _logger.LogInformation("EventProcessorClient started.");
            _healthCheckReporter.Healthy();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to start EventProcessorClient.");
            _healthCheckReporter.Unhealthy("Failed to start EventProcessorClient.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Right after an exception is also thrown and caught by the EventProccessorClient: `An exception occurred while receiving events for Event Hub. Error Message: 'At least one receiver for the endpoint is created with epoch of '0', and so non-epoch receiver is not allowed. Either reconnect with a higher epoch, or make sure all epoch receivers are closed or disconnected.` I am uncertain how intertwined these two are, because I am confident I have seen the blob container warning without the exception following it.

We are using the Azure IoT Hub built-in endpoint and the Consumer group used is $Default.

A fresh container and a restart of the service using the `EventProcessorClient` did not help.
I have no clue how is the client finding blob Ids that are nowhere to be found and/or where is the client looking for these unfound blobs. All other blob related questions on here are usually to do with headers or settings which are handled by the client and not exposed to me. I need help figuring out why are the warnings being thrown every time the service is started although everything seems to be working.
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your container does not exist; while the processor will create blobs as needed, it expects the container to exist when started.  The epoch message is part of startup permissions validation and is benign and expected (and should be caught and swallowed by the processor) .     If your container exists when starting the processor, would you please share the entire stack trace?

Comment: reference for [BlobStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/) ,[Eventhub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send?tabs=passwordless%2Croles-azure-portal) and Azure.Messaging.EventHubs, including the EventProcessorClient [implementation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create Event grid by following the below figure with the function and resource group.

> The error message you are encountering, "Error response: 404 The specified blob does not exist," suggests that the **EventProcessorClient**-- is unable to find a blob that it expects to exist in the Azure storage container used for checkpointing.

[image]

- I am able to create the event subscription by follow. You can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/) for Event hub.

[image]

- Refer this for [Event processor client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient.processeventasync?view=azure-dotnet).

[image]

- Metrics :

[image]